# Efficient way to call a method dynamically based on its name without reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

Let me try to simplify my question:

I have four classes: Admins, Users, Players, Roles

The database returns names of methods that I will need to execute. For example if `Admins_GetName` is returned then `GetName()` method will need to be executed on the `Admins` class.
If `Players_GetRank` is returned then `GetRank()` method will need to be called on the `Players` class.

I don't want to write a huge IF or SWITCH statement with all my business logic in it. What would be the most efficient solution WITHOUT using reflection ? If possibly I would like to avoid the performance hit that reflection brings.

Keep in mind that all methods may have different parameters and but will return strings.

Here is what I'm thinking to do now:
1) Have a method with a switch statement that will break apart the database value and find the  class and method I need to execute.
Something like:

```
switch(DbValue)
{
 case DbValue == "Admins_GetName":
  Declare a delegate to Admins.GetName();
  return;
 case: DbValue = "Players_GetRank"
  Declare a delegate to Players.GetRank();
  return;
  . 
  .
  .
  etc
}
```

return class/method reference;

2) Pass the declaration from above to:

```
var myValue = Retrieved method.invoke()
```

Can you guys suggest me with the best way to accomplish this or help me out with the correct syntax on my idea of how to implement it.

Thank you.

Comment: If all methods may have different parameters and different returns types you will have switch statement anyway.

Comment: Come to think about about they'll always return strings

Answer (score 5):

Needs a little more context; for example, do all the methods in question have the same signature? In the *general* case, reflection is the most appropriate tool for this, and as long as you aren't calling it in a tight loop, it will be fine.

Otherwise, the `switch` statement approach is reasonable, but has the maintenance overhead. If that is problematic, I would be tempted to build a delegate cache at runtime, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        FooUtils.Execute(foo, "B");
        FooUtils.Execute(foo, "D");
    }
}
static class FooUtils
{
    public static void Execute(Foo foo, string methodName)
    {
        methodCache[methodName](foo);
    }
    static readonly Dictionary<string, Action<Foo>> methodCache;
    static FooUtils()
    {
        methodCache = new Dictionary<string, Action<Foo>>();
        foreach (var method in typeof(Foo).GetMethods())
        {
            if (!method.IsStatic && method.ReturnType == typeof(void)
                && method.GetParameters().Length == 0)
            {
                methodCache.Add(method.Name, (Action<Foo>)
                    Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Foo>), method));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public void A() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
    public void B() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
    public void C() { Console.WriteLine("C"); }
    public void D() { Console.WriteLine("D"); }
    public string Ignored(int a) { return ""; }
}
```

That approach can be extended to multiple target types by using generics:

```
static class FooUtils
{
    public static void Execute<T>(T target, string methodName)
    {
        MethodCache<T>.Execute(target, methodName);
    }
    static class MethodCache<T>
    {
        public static void Execute(T target, string methodName)
        {
            methodCache[methodName](target);
        }
        static readonly Dictionary<string, Action<T>> methodCache;
        static MethodCache()
        {
            methodCache = new Dictionary<string, Action<T>>();
            foreach (var method in typeof(T).GetMethods())
            {
                if (!method.IsStatic && method.ReturnType == typeof(void)
                    && method.GetParameters().Length == 0)
                {
                    methodCache.Add(method.Name, (Action<T>)
                        Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>), method));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods will always return strings

Comment: You could implement Func:
static Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>> MethodCache = new Dictionary <string, Func<string, string>>();

static void Execute(string methodName, string a)
{
   var result = MethodCache[methodName](a);
{

static void Initialize(Foo foo)
{
   foreach(var method in typeof(Foo).GetMethods())
   {
      if(!method.IsStatic && method.ReturnType == typeof(string) // other parameter checks here...
         MethodCache.Add(method.Name, (Func<string, string>), Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, string>), foo, method));
      }
}